# Is there a chart available for the historical relationship between Bitcoin price vs difficulty?

Tags: difficulty, exchange-rate

All I've seen is this, from 2011-would like something more updated, if available.

[Is there empirical data about a relationship between bitcoin price and difficulty?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/419/is-there-empirical-data-about-a-relationship-between-bitcoin-price-and-difficult)